# How this Unity code Quaternion.LookRotation work and what it is mean?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

I've gone through Unity's documentation for `Quaternion.LookRotation`, but I didn't get the full understanding of how it works.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;

        // the second argument, upwards, defaults to Vector3.up
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
        transform.rotation = rotation;
    }
}
```

Comment: To be able to better answer your question please edit your post to include what specific part of the concept you are struggling with or at least what your current understanding of the matter is. I know it is hard to ask specific questions without a complete understanding of the topic but putting effort into it will bring you 75% of the way to the answer and maybe we can help from there.

Comment: Well it returns a rotation that makes your object look into a certain direction. No big magic ;) What exactly do you lot understand about it?

Answer (score 3):

A way to visualize a rotation is with three perpendicular axis-ex. A quaternion is a more compact representation, but you can still view it as having three axis-es.

`LookRotation` will align one of the rotation axes to the given direction, but with only one direction there is one degree of freedom left, the other two rotation axes.

That is what the 'up' vector is for, it locks in one of the other axes and forces it to be perpendicular to both the direction and up-vector. The third rotation axis is always perpendicular to both, so we have three perpendicular axes, i.e. a complete rotation.

You can do something similar yourself with a cross product, since that produces a perpendicular vector to two others. Pseudocode:

```
var xDir = direction;
var zDir= xDir.CrossProduct(upVector)
var yDir = zDir.CrossProduct(xDir)
var matrix = CreateARotationMatrixFromAxises(xDir, yDir, zDir)
var quaternion = CreateQuaternionFromRotationMatrix(matrix)
```

Note that the direction and up-vector cannot be parallel, or you will get some kind of error.

Answer (score -5):

There is absolutely no reason for beginners and hobbyist programmers to touch Quaternions.  Unity should remove it from the documentation.

What you want is simply the [`LookAt` command](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). Fortunately, it's incredibly easy to use.

Say you have a `tree` that you want your character to look at, it's this simple:

```
transform.LookAt(tree);
```

Comment: Not sure why people are so afraid of `Quaternion` .. it is literally a ready to use "library" that does all the complex maths behind it for you ^^ It would really get complex if you would need to calculate that stuff on your own ..  and well, yes, `Transform.LookAt` basically does the same for now ... But now try to interpolate that in order to have a smooth rotation ;)

Comment: We use quats to avoid gimble lock. I'm not sure why you say no one should use them. A lot of programmers can't derive a projection matrix on their own. Do you think they shouldn't use perspective?

Comment: @Fattie well maybe .. or you are underestimating the common programmer a lot ;) Of course nobody should touch Quaternions in a sense of manually calculate the individual components ... That's what the type `Quaternion` already takes all care of for you .. the se way you could just say don't touch `Vector3` .. better just leave your objects right where they are ^^ OP asked what `Quaternion.LookRotation` is good for and how it works .. you answered none of that actually ;) `Unity should remove it from the doco` is probably the most short sighted statement I came across today ^^

Comment: If you want to learn programming apps in 3D and Unity .. well then there won't be a away around also learning some basic API reading and .. yes .. maths! At some point you'll have to deal with it and not avoid it where possible .. the sooner you start the better